# Nativescript debugging with visual studio code not work properly

Tags: visual-studio-code, nativescript

I'm try to debug the nativescript application in visual studio code but it have some problem.

The debugger stopper at the breakpoint but the variable window has not data. However, the watch window has data:
[image]

My launch.js file:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch on iOS",
        "type": "nativescript",
        "request": "launch",
        "platform": "ios",
        "appRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "watch": true
    },
    {
        "name": "Attach on iOS",
        "type": "nativescript",
        "request": "attach",
        "platform": "ios",
        "appRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "watch": false
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch on Android",
        "type": "nativescript",
        "request": "launch",
        "platform": "android",
        "appRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "watch": true
    },
    {
        "name": "Attach on Android",
        "type": "nativescript",
        "request": "attach",
        "platform": "android",
        "appRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "watch": false
    }
   ]
}
```

I'm using Genymotion for emulator
Do I missing any configuration?

Comment: Please don't post text as images. Code should be included as text and formatted as code. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Did any one face with this problem? I still not manage to get it work, I tried:
- Re-install nativescript plugin
- Re create launch file

Comment: I have the same issue. For iOS variables are shown for Android not. Have you found a solution for this?